# JHipster ldap Authentication

Tags: java, spring-mvc, authentication, ldap, jhipster

Hey Overfloweens and JHipsters,
I've recently come to the conclusion that I want to try to link up my JHipster security to protocol to an ldap server to verify authentication across my work directory that already has all the employee passwords and usernames. However, I want to continue to use JHipster's in-built token system which uses Spring-mvc. I know how to do the ldap server apart from JHipster, but I'm unclear how to modify the SecurityConfiguration.java file to make this a reality. Any advice would be much appreciate.

Security Configuration file:

```
package com.comcast.castit.config;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.core.env.Environment;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.authentication.builders.AuthenticationManagerBuilder;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.UserDetailsService;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.StandardPasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.security.web.authentication.RememberMeServices;

import com.comcast.castit.security.AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler;
import com.comcast.castit.security.AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler;
import com.comcast.castit.security.AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler;
import com.comcast.castit.security.AuthoritiesConstants;
import com.comcast.castit.security.Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Inject
    private Environment env;

    @Inject
    private AjaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler;

    @Inject
    private AjaxAuthenticationFailureHandler ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler;

    @Inject
    private AjaxLogoutSuccessHandler ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler;

    @Inject
    private Http401UnauthorizedEntryPoint authenticationEntryPoint;

    @Inject
    private UserDetailsService userDetailsService;

    @Inject
    private RememberMeServices rememberMeServices;

    @Bean
    public PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() {
    return new StandardPasswordEncoder();
    }

    @Inject
    public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
        throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(
        passwordEncoder());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
    web.ignoring().antMatchers("/bower_components/**")
        .antMatchers("/fonts/**").antMatchers("/images/**")
        .antMatchers("/scripts/**").antMatchers("/styles/**")
        .antMatchers("/views/**").antMatchers("/i18n/**")
        .antMatchers("/swagger-ui/**");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.exceptionHandling()
        .authenticationEntryPoint(authenticationEntryPoint).and()
        .rememberMe().rememberMeServices(rememberMeServices)
        .key(env.getProperty("jhipster.security.rememberme.key")).and()
        .formLogin().loginProcessingUrl("/app/authentication")
        .successHandler(ajaxAuthenticationSuccessHandler)
        .failureHandler(ajaxAuthenticationFailureHandler)
        .usernameParameter("j_username")
        .passwordParameter("j_password").permitAll().and().logout()
        .logoutUrl("/app/logout")
        .logoutSuccessHandler(ajaxLogoutSuccessHandler)
        .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID").permitAll().and().csrf().disable()
        .headers().frameOptions().disable().authorizeRequests()
        .antMatchers("/app/rest/register").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/app/rest/activate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/app/rest/authenticate").permitAll()
        .antMatchers("/app/rest/logs/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/app/**").authenticated()
        .antMatchers("/metrics/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/health/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/trace/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/dump/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/shutdown/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/beans/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/info/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/autoconfig/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/env/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/trace/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/api-docs/**")
        .hasAuthority(AuthoritiesConstants.ADMIN)
        .antMatchers("/protected/**").authenticated();

    }

    @EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
    private static class GlobalSecurityConfiguration extends
        GlobalMethodSecurityConfiguration {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default authentication mechanism uses a "UserDetailsService" implementation, it should be called "com.comcast.castit.security.UserDetailsService" in your project.

This code has a simple "loadUserByUsername" that fetches a user according to his login and gets his authorities.

For your needs, you should change this part -> this will not impact the rest of your application, which is good (Spring Security is well designed for that)

There is a tutorial on using LDAP with Spring Security / Spring Boot, you can check it out here: https://spring.io/guides/gs/authenticating-ldap/

Of course it would be better if we had a specific documentation for JHipster, so if you succeed and have time, your feedback would be most welcomed!

Answer (score 2):

In `SecurityConfiguration.java` change `configureGlobal` function to:

```
@Inject
public void configureGlobal(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    /*auth
        .userDetailsService(userDetailsService)
            .passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder());*/

    auth.ldapAuthentication()
    .userSearchBase("ou=Users")
    .userSearchFilter("(uid={0})")
    .groupSearchBase("ou=Groups")
    .groupSearchFilter("member={0}")
    .contextSource()
    .url("ldap://127.0.0.1:10389/o=myorganisation");
}
```

I have commented out the the previous code.
Then your application will authenticate with your ldap server. It will still check the database for user details and if the user doesn't exist in users table you will have problems like :
`userRepository.findOneByLogin(login)` that searches for a user in database using the existing username.

But the authentication will happen with your ldap credentials.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the following Code Snippet From the SecurityConfig.java

```
@Override
@Bean
public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception {
return (AuthenticationManager) ldapAuthenticationManager;
}
```

And Then Create an LDAPAuthenticationManager class

```
package com.digitronic.isda.security;

import org.springframework.ldap.core.AuthenticationSource;
import org.springframework.ldap.core.support.LdapContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.BindAuthenticator;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.authentication.LdapAuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.ldap.search.FilterBasedLdapUserSearch;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component("authenticationManagerBean")
public class LDAPAuthenticationManager implements AuthenticationManager {


    LdapAuthenticationProvider provider = null;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication arg0)
            throws AuthenticationException {

        return provider.authenticate(arg0);
    }

    LDAPAuthenticationManager() {

        DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource contextSource = new DefaultSpringSecurityContextSource(
                "ldap://127.0.0.1:389");
        contextSource.setUserDn("test.com\\Administrator");
        contextSource.setCacheEnvironmentProperties(true);
        try {
            contextSource.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {

            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        contextSource.setPassword("asdasdasdjBj,K");

        LdapContextSource ldapSrc = new LdapContextSource();
        ldapSrc.setUrl("ldap://127.0.0.1:389");
        ldapSrc.setUserDn("test.com\\Administrator");
        ldapSrc.setPassword("asdasdasdjBj,K");
        ldapSrc.setAnonymousReadOnly(false);
        ldapSrc.setCacheEnvironmentProperties(true);

        try {
            ldapSrc.afterPropertiesSet();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        ldapSrc.setAuthenticationSource(new AuthenticationSource() {

            @Override
            public String getPrincipal() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "test.com\\Administrator";
            }

            @Override
            public String getCredentials() {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                return "asdasdasdjBj,K";
            }
        });

        FilterBasedLdapUserSearch userSearch = new FilterBasedLdapUserSearch(
                "cn=Users,dc=digitronic,dc=lan", "(sAMAccountName={0})",
                ldapSrc);

        BindAuthenticator bindAuth = new BindAuthenticator(contextSource);
        bindAuth.setUserSearch(userSearch);
        provider = new LdapAuthenticationProvider(bindAuth);
    }
}
```

Comment: @Component("authenticationManagerBean") will also be required as it isn't mentioned in jhibster code.

Answer (score 1):

If you need an UserDetailsContextMapper (For Authorities) add this:

```
provider.setUserDetailsContextMapper(new UserDetailsContextMapper() {

        @Override
        public void mapUserToContext(UserDetails user, DirContextAdapter ctx) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        @Override
        public UserDetails mapUserFromContext(DirContextOperations ctx,
                String username,
                Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> authorities) {

            User anwender = userRepository.findOneByAnwender(username);

            Collection<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
            GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority = new SimpleGrantedAuthority(
                    "ROLE_ADMIN");
            grantedAuthorities.add(grantedAuthority);

            return new org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User(
                    username, "1", grantedAuthorities);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to maintain the JHipster's in-built token system with LDAP I've taken a different approach.
Whenever a user tries to login I search his credentials in the LDAP server and in case it exists, a new user is created in the local database with its LDAP attributes and then all the functionalities work normally.

The following class is used just to get the context of your LDAP server and the user attributes.

```
public class LDAPHelper {

private static LDAPHelper instance = null;

protected LDAPHelper() {
    // Exists only to defeat instantiation
}

public static LDAPHelper getInstance() {
    if (instance == null) {
        instance = new LDAPHelper();
    }
    return instance;
}

public boolean validateLogin(String username, String password) {
    return (getLdapContext(username, password) != null);
}

private LdapContext getLdapContext(String username, String password) {
    Hashtable<String, String> env = new Hashtable<String, String>();

    env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY,
            "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    env.put("com.sun.jndi.ldap.read.timeout", "120000");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "Simple");
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, "VF-ROOT\\" + username);
    env.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, password);
    env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "*ldap url*");
    System.out.println(username);
    try {
        return new InitialLdapContext(env, null);
    } catch (NamingException e) {
        return null;
    }
}

public User getUserAttributes(String username, String password)
        throws NamingException { ... }
```

In the AccountResource I changed the register method to search the user in the LDAP server and, if the user exists, I add him to the local database if he hasn't been added yet. 
You call this method before the login to make sure that only the users that are in the LDAP server can login in your application.

```
     @RequestMapping(value = "/register", method = RequestMethod.POST, produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE,
        MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN_VALUE })
@Timed
public ResponseEntity<?> registerAccount(@Valid @RequestBody ManagedUserDTO managedUserDTO,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    HttpHeaders textPlainHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
    textPlainHeaders.setContentType(MediaType.TEXT_PLAIN);

    // user exists in LDAP server
    if (LDAPHelper.getInstance().validateLogin(managedUserDTO.getLogin(), managedUserDTO.getPassword())) {

        // user was already created in the local database
        if (userRepository.findOneByLogin(managedUserDTO.getLogin().toLowerCase()).isPresent()) {

            return new ResponseEntity<>("user exists in database", textPlainHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);

        } else {

            try {
                User userAux = LDAPHelper.getInstance().getUserAttributes(managedUserDTO.getLogin(), managedUserDTO.getPassword());                             

                User user = userService.createUserInformation(managedUserDTO.getLogin(), managedUserDTO.getPassword(), userAux.getFirstName(),
                        userAux.getLastName(), userAux.getEmail(), managedUserDTO.getLangKey());                                        

                } catch (NamingException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                return new ResponseEntity<>("user created in database", textPlainHeaders, HttpStatus.OK);
            }
        } else {
            return new ResponseEntity<>("user does not exist in ldap", textPlainHeaders, HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED);
        }
}
```